# Javascript regular expression - number before percent sign

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string say:

```
 var currentLabel = "Uploading file... 0%"
```

This is the initial state when the upload starts and I need to update it as the operation runs. I need to take that 0 and replace it with a new number, however I can't just get a substring since it will change to 2 digits eventually and the length will change...

If the length was constant I could do:

```
var newLabel = currentLabel.substring(0, currentLabel.length - 2) + percent + "%";
```

I'm guessing I need a regular expression or really any other way.

Comment: Why can't you do `var newLabel = "Uploading file... " + percent + "%";`

Comment: `var newLabel = currentLablel.replace(/\d+/, percent);`, then you can specify the string  to be whatever you like, the above just replaces the number (just hope there is only one…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do it with a combination of `indexOf` and `substring`, but a regex does make it simpler:

```
newLabel = currentLabel.replace(/\d+$/, percent + "%");
```

There's no other numbers in the string, right?

You could also just write the string again .. it would probably be even less expensive than the regex.

Comment: True! My initial thought was that it would cause a flicker but it doesn't so I just replace it. Your regex works also.

Answer (score 0):

Certianally could be done with a regex and simple replacement

```
([\S\s]+?[\d]+([%])
```

Replace string

```
$1 "new percentage" $2
```

Answer (score 0):

/.*([0-9]+)\%/
something like this will give you the number. but really this is a long way around to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regexp in this case:

```
var currentLabel = "Uploading file... ";
var newLabel = currentLabel + percent + "%";
```